# Javascript reduce example

Tags: javascript

Why is this simple example of plain Javascript reduce not working?

```
// expected output: ["red", "yellow", "blue"]
var primaryColors = [
  { color: 'red' },
  { color: 'yellow' },
  { color: 'blue' }
];

primaryColors.reduce({
  function(previous, primaryColor) {
    previous.push(primaryColor.color);
    return previous;
  }
}, []); 
// VM607:2 Uncaught TypeError: #<Object> is not a function
// at Array.reduce (native)
// at <anonymous>:2:15
```

Comment: This is a typo issue, you simply have to remove the braces around `function () {} `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the signature of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function the first parameter of it should be a `function`,

```
primaryColors.reduce(function(previous, primaryColor) {
  previous.push(primaryColor.color);
  return previous;
}, []);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/p19dcs8n/)

Additionally, this scenario is a best fit for [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),

```
var result = primaryColors.map(function(primaryColor) {
  return primaryColor.color;
}, []);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/p19dcs8n/1/)

Comment: Or `let result = primaryColors.map(i => i.color);`

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is on the right track, but syntax is a bit wrong. `reduce` takes a function callback as the first argument, whereas you have an object literal:

```
primaryColors.reduce(function(previous, primaryColor) {
    previous.push(primaryColor.color);
    return previous;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per previous answers, the callback to [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) receives the following argument list `(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array)`

But this whole thing can be simplified to:

```js
const primaryColors = [
  { color: 'red' },
  { color: 'yellow' },
  { color: 'blue' }
]; 

const result = primaryColors.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat([el.color]), []);

console.log(result)
```